# Create a SharePoint folder if it doesn't exists

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013

I need to create a folder in SharePoint document library only if it doesn't exist, then upload a file to it.
This is the code I'm using:

```
public static bool FolderExists(Web web, string listTitle, string folderUrl)
{
    var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
    var folders = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllFoldersQuery());
    web.Context.Load(list.RootFolder);
    web.Context.Load(folders);
    web.Context.ExecuteQuery();
    var folderRelativeUrl = string.Format("/{0}/{1}", list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, folderUrl);
    return Enumerable.Any(folders, folderItem => (string)folderItem["FileRef"] == folderRelativeUrl);
}

private static void CreateFolder(Web web, string listTitle, string folderName)
{
    var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
    var folderCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation
    {
        UnderlyingObjectType = FileSystemObjectType.Folder,
        LeafName = folderName
    };
    var folderItem = list.AddItem(folderCreateInfo);
    folderItem.Update();
    web.Context.ExecuteQuery();
}

public void UploadFile(string CourseId, string path)
{
    string libraryName = "Documents";
    using (ClientContext clientContext = GetContextObject())
    {
        // if a folder doesn't exists, create it
        if (!FolderExists(clientContext.Web, libraryName, CourseId))
        {
            CreateFolder(clientContext.Web, libraryName, CourseId);

        }

        // if exists, upload input file in Documents/FolderName given by CourseId
        Web web = clientContext.Web;
        List list3 = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
        clientContext.Load(list3.RootFolder);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(fileStream.Name);
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, list3.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl.ToString() + "/" + CourseId + "/" + path.Split('\\').Last(), fileStream, true);
        }

    }

}
```

The problem is the following: these functions work well, but if a folder already exists, try to create it again causing an exception, instead it would only upload the file in "CourseId" folder skipping its creation. How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code that will helps you to check whether the sharepoint folder exists or not

```
 using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

 namespace SharePoint.Client.Extensions
 {
 public static class WebExtensions
 {
    public static bool TryGetFileByServerRelativeUrl(this Web web, string serverRelativeUrl, out File file)
    {
        var ctx = web.Context;
        try
        {
            file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(serverRelativeUrl);
            ctx.Load(file);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            return true;
        }
        catch (ServerException ex)
        {
            if (ex.ServerErrorTypeName == "System.IO.FileNotFoundException")
            {
                file = null;
                return false;
            }
            throw;
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It can't help me but it's a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following line of code in the FolderExists method

```
var folderRelativeUrl = string.Format("/{0}/{1}", list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, folderUrl);
```

to

```
var folderRelativeUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}", list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, folderUrl);
```

**Note: modify "/{0}/{1}" to "{0}/{1}"**